# How to show a modal when a table row is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a `modal` when a table row is clicked. Below are the important parts of the code. I am using `Bootstrap`.

```
  <%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Passport</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery -->

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "scrollY":        "200px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging":         false
                } );
            } );


            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
                    $('#editModal').modal('show');
            });
            });

        </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar_top"> 
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top mytopbar" > 
    <!-- Top Menu Items -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav myul">
      <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> William Harold <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> Inbox</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i> Settings</a> </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default mynav" id="navbar_second">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header menu">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn menu" id="menu-toggle"><img src="images/icon_menu.png" width="20" height="20"/>Menu</a> </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="search_input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start typing a patient name..">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><img src="images/search.png" /></button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-gear"></i>Recent</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
</nav>
<div id="wrapper"> 

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="main-sidebar-wrapper" style="margin-top:50px; width:150px;">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <li> <a href="#"> Face Sheet</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Designation</a> </li>
      <li class="li_active" > <a href="#">Passport</a> </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper --> 

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav main-nav" style="margin-top:10px;">
      <li > <a href="#"> <span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"> Home</span> </a> </li>
      <li class="main-nav-active"> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"> Patients</span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"> Calender</span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"> Tasks</span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"> Billing </span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"> Documents </span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" aria-hidden="true"> Reports </span></a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"> Meaningful</span></a> </li>
      <hr>
      <li> <a href="#"><span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"> Admin</span></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <div class="row row-top">
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:50px;">
      <div class="col-md-3"> <img src="images/img6.jpg" width="70" height="70"/>
        <p style="border-bottom:solid #666 1px;"><strong>John Generalmend Demo</strong></p>
        <p>17 Jul 1956 (58 yrs)</p>
        <p>0123456789</p>
      </div>
         <!--
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <p>ALLERGIES</p>
        <div class="allergy_box">Peanut</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7   ">
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-sm"><img alt="print" title="print" src="images/mailButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">Pt. Msg</span></button>
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-sm"><img alt="print" title="print" src="images/printButton.png" width="30" height="20"/> <span class="help_button">Print</span></button>
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-sm"><img alt="print" title="print" src="images/bookButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">Pt. Ed. </span></button>
        <button class="dropdown btn btn-default btn-sm" id="dropdown">
        <img alt="print" title="print" src="images/noteButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">+ Note</span> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> link</a> </li>
        </ul>
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown btn btn-default btn-sm" id="dropdown">
        <img alt="print" title="print" src="images/scriptButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">Scripts</span> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> link</a> </li>
        </ul>
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown btn btn-default btn-sm" id="dropdown">
        <img alt="print" title="print" src="images/ordersButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">Orders</span> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> link</a> </li>
        </ul>
        </button>
        <button class="dropdown btn btn-default btn-sm" id="dropdown">
        <img alt="print" title="print" src="images/exchangeButton.png" width="30" height="20"/><span class="help_button">Exchange</span> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i> link</a> </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> link</a> </li>
        </ul>
        </button>
      </div>
        -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px">


    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="PassportSrvlt?idEmployee=1" >
          <fieldset id="modal_form">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Passport Number</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input id="textinput" name="passportNumber" type="text" value="${requestScope.passportNumber}" class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>


             <!-- Text input-->

              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="textinput">Passport date</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input id="textinput" name="passportDate" type="date" value="${requestScope.passportDate}" class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>
            <!-- button-->
               <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

            </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>


    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6" > <small><u>Reminder Section</u></small>
              <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="checkboxes"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" id="div_above_table"> <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">+ New Reminder</a> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date Renewal</th>
                <th>Reminder Date</th>
                <th>Reminder Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Date Renewal</th>
                <th>Reminder Date</th>
                <th>Reminder Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr class='clickable-row' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" style="cursor:pointer">
            <td> <c:out value="${currentPassportBean.dateRenewalDue}"/></td>
            <td> <c:out value="${currentPassportBean.reminderDate}"/></td>
            <td> Active</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="historyPassportBean" items="${requestScope['historyPassportBean']}" >
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${historyPassportBean.dateRenewalIssued}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${historyPassportBean.dateRenewalIssued}"/></td>
                <td>Deactivated</td>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
          <!-- /.row --> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper --> 

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper --> 

<!-- Menu Toggle Script --> 
<script>
$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    $("#menu-toggle").hover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").hover(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });







    </script> 

<!-- add New Job modal -->

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"> <img src="images/arrow-back-512.png"  width="30px" height="30px"> <small>Back</small></a> <span id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left:20px;"><font size="+2"><b>Add to problem list</b></font></span> </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="InsertPassportReminderSrvlt?idEmployee=1" >
          <fieldset id="modal_form">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Renewal Due</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="dateRenewalDue" type="date"  class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Reminder Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="reminderDate" type="date" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /add New Job modal -->


<!-- Edit  Job modal -->

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"> <img src="images/arrow-back-512.png"  width="30px" height="30px"> <small>Back</small></a> <span id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left:20px;"><font size="+2"><b>Add to problem list</b></font></span> </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="InsertPassportReminderSrvlt?idEmployee=1" >
          <fieldset id="modal_form">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Renewal Due</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="dateRenewalDue" type="date"  class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Reminder Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="reminderDate" type="date" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /Edit Job modal -->
</body>
</html>
```

Please pay attention to this area

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" style="cursor:pointer">
```

That is where I am trying to show that model when the row is clicked. However, nothing is happening. I am not a designer, how can I fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using data-attributes and JavaScript to initialize/show your modal, it's meant to be [one or the other.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage)

In your example, remove your modal js the modal should show correctly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* this is not needed
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    });
    */
});
```

You are also missing a closing `</div>` in the markup of both of your modals:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"> <img src="images/arrow-back-512.png" width="30px" height="30px"> <small>Back</small>
                </a><span id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left:20px;"><font size="+2"><b>Add to problem list</b></font></span>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="InsertPassportReminderSrvlt?idEmployee=1">
                    <fieldset id="modal_form">
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Renewal Due</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input name="dateRenewalDue" type="date" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Reminder Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input name="reminderDate" type="date" class="form-control input-md">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- This is missing from both modals -->
```

[Working JSFiddle with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/y93dnb5h/).

Comment: The problem is the same, you **don't** need the `$('#editModal').modal('show');` in your JavaScript if you are using data-attributes to activate your modal.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JavaScript console? (ctrl + shift + J on Chrome).


Your HTML is also formatted correctly and contains additional double-quotes: `<span" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true">` though this shouldn't be breaking the bootstrap modal.

Comment: You're also missing closing `</div>` tags on both modals. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hey, you found the answer. The unclosed </div> stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `jQuery` code in your question isn't needed and you didn't include your modal HTML. However, if you use your code as is, remove the jQuery and add a modal with an id of `editModal` it will work. This is because your clickable row has a data-target of `#editModal` and Bootstrap picks this up for you.

For example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date Renewal</th>
      <th>Reminder Date</th>
      <th>Reminder Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Date Renewal</th>
      <th>Reminder Date</th>
      <th>Reminder Status</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr class='clickable-row' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" style="cursor:pointer">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>


<!-- Edit  Job modal -->

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal"> <img src="images/arrow-back-512.png"  width="30px" height="30px"> <small>Back</small></a> <span id="myModalLabel" style="margin-left:20px;"><font size="+2"><b>Add to problem list</b></font></span> </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="InsertPassportReminderSrvlt?idEmployee=1" >
          <fieldset id="modal_form">

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Date Renewal Due</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name="dateRenewalDue" type="date"  class="form-control input-md" >
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Reminder Date</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input  name="reminderDate" type="date" class="form-control input-md"> 
              </div>

            </div>



      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
                </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- /Edit Job modal -->
```

Comment: Is the Bootstrap js file added *after* the jQuery js file?

Comment: OK, Let me update the question with full code. Please note it contains some JSTL Code as well, as this is aJSP file.

Comment: @JustCause As far as I can tell there is essentially nothing wrong with your code other than the unneeded jQuery that I said to remove. Some questions: Which version of jQuery are you referencing? Which version of Boostrap are you referencing? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The versions are potentially critical, where did you get the files from?

Comment: Open the files, they should have the version number at the top.

Comment: This is from "Bootstrap.css". The version is - `Bootstrap v3.3.1`

Comment: Also need the jQuery and Bootstrap js version?

Comment: Thank you very much for continuous support. I really appreciate it. The issue was with unclosed `<div>` tags.